# xterm is displaying raw escape sequences

Tags: xterm

I currently have an old Red Hat Enterprise Linux server (release 6.7).  From this server I’m able to open an xterm and telnet to an OpenVMS machine.  Once connected to OpenVMS I can run LSE (the language sensitive editor) with no issues.

Now, I have a new CentOS server to replace the Red Hat server but when I connect to my OpenVMS machine, it appears as if xterm is just printing the escape characters rather than interpreting them correctly.

For example, I seeing sequences similar to ]?K?21;H?;7m being printed.

I’ve been trying to see if there are configuration difference between to old server and the new server but I haven’t found much.  In both cases, the TERM environment variable is set to xterm-256color and the locales also seem to match.

Comment: If you're not actually running *xterm*, your terminal likely doesn't support certain control characters that VMS might send.  (The `TERM` environment variable is irrelevant).

Comment: It is possible that the new xterm is not compiled or set to manage the ANSI escape sequences. Try locally (and remotely) with `echo -e "\0033[31;47m $USER \0033[0m"`; In xterm this can be controlled by the options `-cm` and `+cm`. See `man xterm`

Comment: I am running xterm to emulate a VT100.  The command is basically xterm -xrm backarrowKeyIsErase -e telnet hostaddr.  Entering the sequences manually works as expected in a new xterm window and again after establishing the telnet connection.  It’s LSE that doesn’t seem to work anymore.

Comment: I have not used LSE, so I don't know any details about it. Is there some settings/configuration file or some option, that might have changed between the versions?

Comment: Are there settings or options that might have changed?  Well, that’s what I trying to figure out.  OpenVMS and LSE have not changed.  The command I’m using to open xterm and telnet to OpenVMS has not changed.  The difference seems to be between Red Hat and CentOS but I just cannot see what the difference is.

Comment: Let us hope that somebody who is using LSE and/or Centos will see your thread and help you.

Comment: I can log in to CentOS Stream release 8 remotely and get colour high-lighting in the editors vim and nano. Are there many advantages with LSE?

Comment: Strikes me that what you may have here is an issue with the terminal ID string. If the xterm on the RHEL machine identifies itself as a VT100 in response to a query, and the one on the Centos machine identifies itself as something different, LSE may be sending different control strings than it should be. Alas, I can't tell you where to find that.

Comment: Well, I’ve managed to try this from a different CentOS machine and it works.  So there must be some configuration or missing package on my new machine.  I just need to find out what’s different.